# Samba creates two files on copy of one file

Tags: centos, mac-osx, samba, share

I've set up Samba share on a Centos system and all works fine except whenever I copy a file using OS X Finder to a share it makes two files, the actual file and what looks to be a log file, which has an appending ._ on the front of it.

So for example if I copy index.php it copies that one, plus it creates ._index.php with semi looking log info in it.

How do I stop Samba doing this? I'm sure its in smb.conf somewhere but can't find it.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not Samba, it's the OS X client.  Since the Samba share doesn't support Mac-style file attributes (resource fork, type&creator codes, Finder flags, extended attributes, etc), the OS X file system will split the file into the [AppleDouble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleDouble) format, storing the data fork (regular file contents) as one file, and all of the unsupported metadata in a second file with a "._" prefix on the name.

I don't think there's any way to stop the OS X client from doing this (there's [a way to prevent ".DS_Store" files](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1629), but that doesn't work for the AppleDouble files).  There are various programs and scripts that'll remove the AppleDouble files (e.g. [BlueHarvest](http://www.zeroonetwenty.com/blueharvest4/)).  Unfortunately, for some file types they're actually an integral part of the file (these are, of course, Mac-specific formats like Finder aliases), so depending on what kind of files you're storing, you might wind up deleting something important.

Comment: heh, They must have a script at work that deletes it because I've never had this problem on that network. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the trick is to hide system files on windows machine. This way you shouldn't see files beginning with dot "."

Comment: I actually dont see them, more the principle behind the matter.

Comment: Well, the correct way of handling such a situation is to use an alternative data stream, which is not possible because of NTFS

Comment: There is no NTFS or windows machines in use here